# Can you force windows (10) not to re-index?

Tags: search-indexing

My Windows 10 keeps reindexing every couple of days (from the very beginning) and I want to know if there is a way, once indexing is finished, I do not let it re-index.

Comment: Would completely disabling the search's index be acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  No, because I presume that doing so, I won't be able to search my files.  Having said that, I haven't actually tried it, so I don't know. I guess I can try it next time index is completed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can still search files, but will only be searching the drive when you actually want to search, and not every few days like it's doing now, so each search will probably be a lot slower. Depends how often you search & how critical the time is

Comment: If indexing is on, it will rely on the index.  Anything added or changed since the index won't be found.  You should either disable indexing entirely, or fix the problem with the way it reindexes.

Comment: Anecdotally, I've found that, regardless of indexing, using good third-party search utilities can be a viable alternative to Windows Search (even if speed is a concern). They can be more accurate as well, depending on circumstance.

Comment: I've used a couple of alternatives to Windows Search but they either only search titles or if they searching inside the files (I have many pdf files), they take a very long time or are not accurate.